# i cant find or add specific components to my objects in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have been watching tutorials on youtube (i'm new to unity), I was trying to add a rigid body to my player, which I've never done. In the video they clicked add component in the inspector then physics then rigid body. but i don't see physics and when I search for it nothing appears. the only options i get are:

Effects
Layout
Mesh
Miscellaneous
Rendering
New Script

Underneath Box Collider i get a warning saying the the "module that implements this component type has been force excluded in player settings" could this be the problem? If so how would i fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: you can share your effort here. You can share pics, diagrams, flowcharts, pseudo-codes, and codes to the community.

Answer (score 1):

Try go to the [`PackageManager`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui.html), switch to [`Built-In Packages`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui-filter.html) and see if the package `Physics` is installed. Sounds like it has been actively be removed (uninstalled) or you somehow broke the `Packages/manifest.json` file.

If you can't even get the `PackageManager` try to reset the packages as described [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/package-manager-is-missing.557854/) via the top menu bar → `Help` → `Reset Packages to defaults`

or just directly replace your `Packages/manifest.json` with a one from a fresh empty project

Also note

> Our first TECH stream release of the year is available as of today. Unity 2020.1 includes a wide range of features and improvements that make Unity workflows even more intuitive and make you more productive, **while Unity 2019 LTS remains the recommended version for projects in production.**

The PackageManager got an overhaul and a lot of users had issues like yours. See e.g. [this thrread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/you-do-not-have-entitlement-for-this-package.832555).

**You should stick to the LTS versions, currently [2019.4 LTS](https://unity.com/releases/2019-lts)** (except for **experimenting** with the very newest features).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: it says i don't the entitlements for this package

Comment: Is it possible you are using an **alpha** or **beta** version? See [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/you-do-not-have-entitlement-for-this-package.832555) .. in general rather stick to the latest stable version or even better the LTS versions - currently [`2019.4 LTS`](https://unity.com/releases/2019-lts)!

Comment: i was using 2020.1.3 it wasn't in the alpha or beta section i was reading through the unity forums and some people had problems with this version as well so i remade my project in 2019.4.9 and it has since fixed all of my issues.

Answer (score 0):

So if you type in the search bar of Add Component "Rigid" nothing pops up? If not I believe it should.

The problem could be in your libraries. Try deleting the library in your project (with Unity closed). Maybe if you have not made much progress in this project you could try opening a new unity project and seeing if it works.

Comment: Which library? in the project there are a lot.

Comment: In your project folder for your current project. You will also find a folder called Assets and Logs here, Delete the folder labled Library with unity closed.

Comment: It didn't work, i even reinstalled unity I'm so confused.